# Choose a value between two columns SQL - VBA in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have two columns in a table stored in a SQL database. Column A and column B both contains Boolean value. Is there possible to load only the maximum value between these 2 columns.

IF A >=B THEN A ELIF B AS "MAX_Value" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT case when A >= B Then A else B end as Max_value
FROM yourTableName
```

Comment: You had the logic, just needed the syntax.